# Understand the purpose of "-f" flag in expect scripts shebang

Tags: expect

Shebang of expect scripts is often:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
```

According to expect manual, the `-f` flag is only useful when using the #! notation, so that other arguments may be supplied on the command line. Does this mean that with `#!/usr/bin/expect -f` shebang, the expect handles all the other code in the script-file as command-file and allows user to specify additional commands on the command line, e.g. `/usr/bin/custom-expect-script.exp -c "debug 0; log_file /tmp/expect_log_file.log"`?

Comment: yes. you are correct. You can supply arguments with `-c` flag

Comment: @Dinesh, thanks! Why is `-f` so commonplace in expect shebangs? I mean it's more of a special case when one needs to add additional commands to script with `-c`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. It is a common practice, just to provide any option via command line args to make it if required under possible circumstances.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-f` flag names a file from which to read commands, i.e., a script. Interactively, this may seem pointless. If you say `expect script`, it is assumed that you meant `expect -f script` anyway.

In fact, there is no reason to ever use `-f` from the command line. It is only provided so that it can be used from the `#!` line as:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect -f
```

Just as with `--`, when a script starts out with this `-f` line and is invoked just by its name (without `expect`), it behaves as you had entered the following command:

```
% expect -f script args
```

Now you can use Expect flags such as `-c` and they will be correctly handled. Since the `-f script` looks like a flag, Expect continues looking and finds the `-c` and interprets this as a flag, too.

```
% echo.exp -c "set debug 1" foo bar 17
```

**echo.exp**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
if { $debug } { 
    puts "debugging on"
} else { 
    puts "turned off debugging"
}
puts $argc
lassign $argv x y z
puts "$x, $y and $z"
```

With `-f` flag defined, the script can be executed without `expect` from terminal as

```
 ./echo.exp -c "set debug 1" foo bar 17
```

Else, `expect` will throw error.

The drawback, of course, is that if you want to pass flags to your own script, you then
have to also use `--`. For example, assume you have your own flag defined as `-e` and `-ZZ`:

```
% echo.exp -- -e -ZZ -c
```

`-e` and `-ZZ` are not flags known to Expect, but you must still use the -- or else Expect
will tell you that you have used an illegal flag.

```
% echo.exp -e -zz -c
expect: illegal option -- e
```

Source : [Exploring Expect](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920903.do)